# SharePoint Provider Apps High Security why Windows Auth

Tags: authentication, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have setup a SharePoint dev environment and managed to get a provider hosted app working with Certs etc (High Security)

This is all on-premise and we won't have a connection to ACS (now, I may have miss understood ACS, I presume its azure based and servers need to talk to server outside of the server room :) ).

My problem is:

The SharePoint site will not be using Windows Auth, we will be using a login form which will read details from another store.

If I review the code that VS generates I can see that it expects a Windows identity.

Can this be done? I would have expected my provider app not to need any auth as its hosted via SharePoint, it gets the claim from SharePoint so why does it need a Windows Identity as well as the SharePoint Claims.

Answer (score 0):

As you said : The SharePoint site will not be using Windows Auth, we will be using a login form which will read details from another store.

Ans : You are talking about Form based authentication.

If I review the code that VS generates I can see that it expects a Windows identity.

Ans : You are correct. VS generates the code that expects windows identity [For dev environments]. You need to write separate function to get clientcontext for FBA using SharePointContextProvider class.
Context can be :
CreateAppOnlyClientContextForSPHost(),CreateUserClientContextForSPHost()

I would have expected my provider app not to need any auth as its hosted via SharePoint

Ans : You can make IIS site [Hosting your provider hosted apps] to allow annonymous authentication.

You can get access token with this code.

```
var contextTokenString = TokenHelper.GetContextTokenFromRequest(Page.Request);
            var appWeb = new Uri(clientContext.Web.Url);

            if (contextTokenString != null)
            {
                SharePointContextToken contextToken =
                    TokenHelper.ReadAndValidateContextToken(contextTokenString, Request.Url.Authority);

                string accessToken =
                    TokenHelper.GetAccessToken(contextToken, appWeb.Authority).AccessToken;
}
```

Get current user :-

```
// Get current context to get load siteurl
                var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext);

                string webUrl =spContext.SPHostUrl.ToString();
                //using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
                using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(webUrl))
                {
                    clientContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.FormsAuthentication;
                    clientContext.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo = new FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo(uName, pswd);

                    Web web = clientContext.Web;
                    clientContext.Load(web);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    // Load SP user from login name found from httpcontext
                    string currentSPUser = string.Concat("<<<FBADomainPrefix>>>",User.Identity.Name);
                    var currentUser = clientContext.Web.EnsureUser(currentSPUser);
                    clientContext.Load(currentUser);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Comment: Very helpful, so I should be able to use an anonymous site and use the token to talk to SharePoint user that has launched the app

Comment: Ideally you should. i  have never tried for annomous site.. plz let me know your findings :) it will help us all.

Comment: I am getting my head around it now (I have only been looking in anger for a few hours its all very interesting), I think I need to add app permissions in manifest and this should pass the user details to me. Tbh, I only need to know who the user is for now. Sort if like a facebook app that says "this app needs to know your name" (on my mobile on the train so apologies if I have any typos)

Comment: Steve from blogs i have read token is not generated in high-trust scenario.. i will share the details of getting current user information in app with you..

Comment: Yes please, if you could share the code that would be awesome. Thanks

Comment: I have not forgot about this, I have moved onto other things :) I will be looking at this again and will mark as Answer when I get a chance to try it :) Thanks